# Can batch respond to a dialog box and populate a required filename?

Tags: batch, adobe-acrobat

I tried `echo 'filename.txt' | <command>` but to no avail. The filename was not inputted to the dialog box successfully to fill in the file name field as I need it to.

---

**The dialogue box**

The picture below is the dialog box that pops up. The `<command>` will call the default printer set under "Devices and Printers" of Windows which is Adobe PDF in this case.

I think there are two ways to solve this problem. One is a general way that there is a batch command to input text to dialog box in general. And the other is a specific way to handle the Adobe Printer.

[image]

---

**More Detail**

The command is `abc.exe -batch myplot.ses` and `abc.exe` is software that plots some sort of binary data and when it runs the only human input is the dialog box above. The `-batch` option is used for batch operations. The `myplot.ses` is the file containing how the binary data is plotted (contour, time series, etc.) and I'd like the dialogue box to use the same file name as the `.ses` file for the file name field for saving each as a PDF file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate through `.ses` files in a directory via a [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) loop and use [start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) to execute the executable and pass it the file name of the `.ses` file.  Within the loop per each iteration you can use **variable substitutions** to get the file name from the `.ses` file excluding the extension.

You can pass the file name (without the extension) as the first argument (`%~1`) to [call](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) after the subroutine label name.  That first argument could be incorporated into some dynamic VBScript logic using [sendkeys](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html) to type in the desired output `.pdf` from the **Save PDF File As** dialogue window.

Lastly, use [cscript](http://ss64.com/vb/cscript.html) to execute the dynamically built VBScript so it will perform the emulated keystroke commands accordingly and  manipulate the dialogue windows to help further automate—it's still batch but with some Windows native extended, controllable, and adjustable easy to understand logic.

---

### Script (Batch Example)

**Note:** *You may need to play with the `timeout /t <#>` to specify more or less seconds to wait depending on how long once the `ses` is read into the exe before that window of **Save PDF File As** opens. Same with the `sendkeys TAB <#>` for the number of tabs to press on that window since I was only able to slightly test with **Save Print Output As** title and virtual PDF printer.*

```
@ECHO ON

SET "WinTitle=Save PDF File As"
SET "sesDir=C:\Folder\sesFiles"
SET "exe=C:\Folder\abc.exe"

FOR %%A IN ("%sesDir%\*.ses") DO (
    start "" %exe% -batch "%%~A"
    timeout /t 10
    CALL :dynVBS "%%~NA"
)
EXIT

:dynVBS
SET TempVBSFile=%temp%\~tmp_SavePDFFileAs_Temp.vbs
IF EXIST "%TempVBSFile%" DEL /F /Q "%TempVBSFile%"

ECHO Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 900                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.AppActivate "%WinTitle%"                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 900                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "^a"                               >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{DEL}"                            >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "%~1.pdf"                          >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB 3}"                          >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"                          >>"%TempVBSFile%"
CSCRIPT //nologo "%TempVBSFile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

---

### Further Resources

- [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

  - **Variable Substitutions (FOR /?)**

    > In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been
    >   enhanced. You can now use the following optional syntax:
    >
    > ```
    > %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
    > %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
    > ```
- [start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)
- [timeout](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html)
- [call](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html)
- [sendkeys](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html)
- [appactivate](https://ss64.com/vb/appactivate.html)
- [cscript](http://ss64.com/vb/cscript.html)